# Unity 3D Create Plane at player height

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, plane

I have a player object and am trying to use the mouse to have the player look towards the mouse position. This is working fine but when the player goes up a ramp or it's height changes, the mouse raycast plane doesn't adjust to the height of the player.

```
    // Look input
    Ray ray = viewCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    Plane groundPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up,Vector3.zero);
    float rayDistance;

    if(groundPlane.Raycast(ray,out rayDistance)) {
        Vector3 point = ray.GetPoint(rayDistance);
        //Debug.DrawLine(ray.origin,point,Color.red);
        controller.LookAt(point);
    }
```

I have tried searching for the answer on Google but the lack of results seems to indicate that I am asking the wrong question. I have also looked at the Unity documentation for Plane but I don't understand what I am looking for. Any help would really be appreciated. I am stuck and it's stopped me from progressing on my first game I have ever created.

Comment: You could probably just set the `Y` of `point` to be equal to the player's Y before the call to `LookAt`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried point.y = transform.position.y; before the LookAt and it appears to perform the same. I thought that would work as it seems to make sense but didn't and I don't know why.

Comment: So just following it up, the point x,y,z are based off the raycast. I figure as the raycast is based of the location of the mouse, the x and z would need to be adjusted as well. I believe this is why the change just to y doesn't work.

Comment: What camera style are you working with? Top down? Isometric?

Comment: Here's a thought. Perhaps you don't want to raycast against the ground plane, since that will just return a point on the ground. Instead, what you probably want to do is raycast against a plane at the player's height. That way, the point you get from the raycast will already be at player height.

Comment: I have a script repositioning the camera at 10 y, -20 behind the player on update. It has a LookAt the player as well to get the angle down right.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to create a plane at the player's height. I don't know how to do that. It's the title of the question.

Comment: Have you tried looking it up? Google produces [`GameObject.CreatePrimitive`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.CreatePrimitive.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried everything and the following seemed to work:

```
Plane groundPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up,Vector3.zero);
```

changed to

```
Plane groundPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up,transform.position);
```